# mysql join query problem

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables
1) "products" with fields (productid PK, name, description, price)
2) "sales" with fields (salesid PK, salestime, productid, customername, customeremail, status)

I need to display data in table format as

SalesID      Product Name      Amount      Customer Name      Customer Address      Payment Status

For this, I am using following query

```
SELECT s.salesid, p.name, p.price, s.customername, s.customeremail, s.status 
FROM sales s 
LEFT JOIN products p ON s.productid = p.productid 
ORDER BY salestime DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Is there any way I can still optimize this query to run faster?

Comment: `JOIN` s and `ORDER BY` s are where you will see a slow down, but if you changed those, you wouldn't get back the data you want, in the order you want it. The query looks good to me, but an index on the `salestime` and `product_id` columns would probably help speed things up a bit. Also, can you store this query as a view or stored procedure? When a SQL is called, the server needs to compile the SQL code, then execute it. When it's called from a view or stored proc, it's precompiled by the server, which could save a few more milliseconds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the appropriate indexes on the tables?

Have a look at [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) and [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: if tables are already filled with data, and I index them they won't make any difference? should I remove all data, then create index or is there any other way around?

Comment: NO no no no. Creating the index with data in the tables should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The query is as good as it can be.  By their nature queries specify WHAT to do, not HOW to do it.

It's the RDMS below it that will effect your performance, and the main way to impact a query like this is to add indexes the columns on which you join (each table's oroductid)

Comment: depends on the result you want.  if no match is made between the two tables for a certain row (of your 'left' table) do you want these fields to be displayed along with nulls from the counterpart in the other table (LEFT JOIN)?  or do you just want it to not be listed (INNER JOIN, of which EQUI is a type)?

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine. Try indexing `productid` in both tables, as well as `salestime`.

Comment: if tables are already filled with data, and I index them they won't make any difference? should I remove all data, then create index or is there any other way around?

Comment: Just add the indexes and they'll index the existing data.